# mySql select multiple IDs with possible repeating IDs for shopping cart

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to get the cost of all the items by the IDs and then add them up for a shopping cart. I have two issues:

1.) The users may have more than one item with the same ID. Using the method below mySql will not select the item twice. In the example below I have THREE items with the ID of '01' and TWO items with the ID of '07'. However my select statement will only select each ID once. 
2.) The method I am using below adds a comma at the end of the last ID so my statement will not work. I need the comma's in between each item for the select but not on the last one. How can I resolve this issue?

```
if($_SESSION[InCart])
{
    foreach($_SESSION[InCart] as $result) 
    {
    $Items .= $result . ',';
    } 
}

include('../connect.php');

// EXAMPLE RESULT MAY LOOK LIKE THIS
// echo $Items (would print: 01,09,07,01,01,23,07,)

$sql = "SELECT Cost FROM cartItems WHERE itemNumber IN ('$Items')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$Cost = 0;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $Cost = $Cost + $row["Cost"];
    }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: when you say "the users may have more than one item with the same ID", are you alluding to the _quantity_ in the cart?

Comment: Yes. They may have 3, for example HATS, in the cart. The hat may have an ID of 03 so in my  'InCart' session so it would show up 3 times.

Comment: Then, are you also showing quantity in the cart?  Because usually to represent quantity, i wouldn't expect you to put the same thing in the cart thrice ,but rather to represent quantity as a separate field.  IF you insist on keeping duplicate of each unique ID in the cart instead, @Gordon Linoff has a query that should work for you.  But this seems unlike any cart software I've ever used.

Comment: use `rtrim( $txt, ',')` to right trim the comma off.

Comment: first of in your cart you should track how many of each item they are buying, then it's a simple matter of multiplying.  Why query more data then you need to.  Instead of adding in duplicate items, add a number_of or such to each item, then increment that with more items.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Or just `implode()` it.

Comment: @tyteen4a03 - `implode` is more appropriate in this case as it's already an array ( and a simple one at that ), `rtrim` is just the faster option though if you need to loop over the array to do other things, for example.  The main issue though is the logic in the cart.  Not the SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep track of how many items of each type in your cart.

so in the cart you have now like

```
$items =  [1,1,1,2,6];
```

you should have them like this

```
$items = [
   'item-1' => 3,
   'item-2' => 1,
   'item-6' => 1
];
```

I never use integers for associate keys, if you sort ( or some other array functions ) an array like that it will mess it up by reordering or resetting the numeric keys, `[1=>3,2=>1,6=>1]` could become `[0=>3,1=>1,2=>1]` for example.  You can make it more readable and protect them by prefixing them with a string  like `item-`, So then you just do something like:

```
   $itemIDs = [];
  foreach( $items as $itemID => $Quantity ){
      //replace item- with empty, you could also use substr, or even str_replace.
      $itemIDs[] = (int)preg_replace('/^item-/', '', $itemID);
  }
```

That will give you a list of ids like you have ( minus the duplicates )

```
  $itemIDs = [1,2,6];
```

Do your search and in the while loop

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     //correlate it back to original $items using the key [item-{ID}] to get the quantity
    $Cost += ( $row["Cost"] * $items['item-'.$row['ID']] ); //cost + ( item cost * quantity )
}
```

Multiply the items cost by the quantity in the cart, add that to your sum....

For this bit in  your sql:

```
  $sql = "SELECT Cost FROM cartItems WHERE itemNumber IN ('$Items')";
```

instead do this

```
  $sql = 'SELECT Cost FROM cartItems WHERE itemNumber IN ('.implode(',', $itemIDs) .')';
```

You wont need to quote them because we cast them to int in the `foreach` loop.  This is a regular expression that matches `^` starts with `item-`, so it matches the `item-` and removes it.  ( see it in action here https://regex101.com/r/pLqDWw/1 )

```
    (int)preg_replace('/^item-/', '', $itemID);
```

So that will come out like  ( I think, just doing it in my head )

```
    $sql = 'SELECT Cost FROM cartItems WHERE itemNumber IN (1,2,6)';
```

Which is fine because generally integers don't need to be quoted in MySql.  This also has the benefit of sanitizing them to prevent any Sql Injection, because casting them wont allow any alphabet or special characters though.

I changed the `"` to single quotes `'`, it just makes it look better when used as a query without variable interpolation `"$var"` for example.

UPDATE:  to add items

```
  $items = isset($_SESSION['items']) ? $_SESSION['items'] : []; //check if items array is saved in the session.

  $key = 'item-'.$_POST['itemID'];

  if( !isset( $items[$key] ) ){
       $items[$key] = $_POST['quantity'];
  }else{
      $items[$key] += $_POST['quantity'];
  }

  $_SESSION['items'] = $items;
```

Assuming `$_POST['itemID']` is the items id and `$_POST['quantity']` is the number to add.  Same goes for subtracting except for that I would add

```
  if(  $items[$key] <= 0 ){
    unset(  $items[$key] ); //remove item from list.
 }
```

Comment: wow, I am loving this. Still trying to wrap my head around it. One question tho. How do I add or subtract an item to the array? For example say they want to hit ADD MORE button. I would have to search the array and then add a value. Same with subtracting one and I am not sure how to do this. I am asking this for adding the items to the array. It has nothing to do with the mysql.

Comment: you would take the item id and add `item-` to it. then you can increment or decrement the array.   `++$items['item-'.$itemID]` or `--$items['item-'.$itemID]` or `$items['item-'.$itemID] += 1`  you can check if it exists with `if(!isset($items['item-'.$itemID])) ` as you may have to set the first one.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau - added a simple example for you.

Comment: I think its a good simple approach, it makes it easier to check if an item is in the cart.  We just add `item-` to make sure the id is a string.  PHP can remove the numbered keys when you use some functions on array with numbered keys, So we can keep them safe that way, and it makes it more readable as to what they are.

Comment: I am using it so far. It seems to be working. I will let you know when I get to the mysql part. Thanks so much.

Comment: Sure, I had a few small things I fixed like `implode( ...` missing `)` and `$itemIDS` instead of `$itemIDs`.  I'm just doing it in my head so, make sure to check the syntax...  Otherwise it should work, the theory is good... lol ... I been doing PHP for over 7 years.  So this is pretty simple for me.

Comment: Cool, you should quote these keys in your VID, like `$_SESSION[key]` should be `$_SESSION["key"]` it will work without the quotes, but you will get a PHP Warning of  "Undefined Constant" or such if you have error reporting on `ini_set('display_errors', 1)` and `error_reporting(-1)`  Otherwise it looks like I would expect, with your array output.

Comment: Not sure if you realized it yet or not, but you could easily make a cart review page, where they can add and subtract quantities using a text input, to say add 4 or 5 of an item at a time, instead of just one.

Comment: I am stuck here: How do I get the quantity here? $Cost += ( $row["Cost"] * $items['item-'.$row['ID']] ); - - $items['item-'.$row['ID']] ) is not working. Not sure what to put in the place of ID.

Comment: This seemed to do it: $Cost += ( $row["Cost"] * $_SESSION[InCart]['item-'.$row["itemNumber"]] );

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join` for this calculation -- because you explicit want duplicates.  However, the query is a bit more challenging to generate:

```
SELECT SUM(cost) as cost
FROM cartItems c JOIN
     (SELECT 1 as itemNumber UNION ALL
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
      SELECT 2
     ) i
     ON i.itemNumber = c.itemNumber;
```

Note:  You should use aggregation in the query to add all the values together.  That is the best way to use SQL for this purpose.